# How to convert u'\u03b1-catenin' to α-catenin?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

print u'\u03b1-catenin'
output -  "α-catenin"
I want variable to store value "α-catenin" not u'\u03b1-catenin'.

Comment: What exactly is your question? `α` and `\u03b1` are the same thing, just different representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, the default encoding of the source is assumed to be `ascii`, but you can declare the encoding of the source file with a special comment, then use Unicode symbols directly in the source.  Make sure to save the file in the encoding declared.  Otherwise, the two string definitions are equivalent:

```
#coding:utf8
x = u'α-catenin'
y = u'\u03b1-catenin'
print x
print y
print x==y
```

Output:

```
α-catenin
α-catenin
True
```

For users of Python 3.x, the default encoding is UTF-8, so the special comment is not required if the source is saved in UTF-8 encoding.